# Taking multiple pictures on timer on iPhone11

Tags: iphone, photos, camera

I’m looking for a way to take a number of pictures, say one pic a second over a minute, with my iPhone.

I’m aware of the time-lapse mode on the Camera app, I could record the video then take freeze frames, but beside the hassle, the quality is not high enough.

Also, I’m aware of the self-timer function of the Camera app. That is not good enough as it takes only *one* picture, and I want to take several without having to go back to the phone each time.
Finally, the photo burst setting is not good enough either, as the pictures are too closely spaced in time.

So is there an app or a function that allows me to take one picture every second over an interval of time?